# Searching through an array

Tags: json, jq

Trying to learn how to think in jq script.

Given this data:

```
{
   "characters": [
       { "First": "Fred", "Last": "Weasley" },
       { "First": "George", "Last": "Weasley" },
       { "First": "Hermione", "Last": "Granger" },
       { "First": "Ron", "Last": "Weasley" },
       { "First": "Hagrid" },
       { "First": "Draco", "Last": "Malfoy" },
       { "First": "Molly", "Last": "Weasley" },
       { "First": "Voldemort" },
       { "First": "Lucius", "Last": "Malfoy" }
    ]
}
```

Find all characters with the same last name as "Ron". And no, you don't already know his last name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the last name you are looking for and save it in a variable, then update the `characters` array accordingly:

```sh
jq '
  (.characters[] | select(.First == "Ron").Last) as $last
  | .characters |= map(select(.Last == $last))
'
```

```json
{
  "characters": [
    {
      "First": "Fred",
      "Last": "Weasley"
    },
    {
      "First": "George",
      "Last": "Weasley"
    },
    {
      "First": "Ron",
      "Last": "Weasley"
    },
    {
      "First": "Molly",
      "Last": "Weasley"
    }
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/geZrHBAd49)

---

If you want to make the call with a dynamic first name, provide it using a parameter variable:

```sh
jq --arg first "Ron" '
  (.characters[] | select(.First == $first).Last) as $last
  | .characters |= map(select(.Last == $last))
'
```

Comment: That works! There was a point where I was trying to save as a variable, but by the time I got it, only Ron was left in my list. Didn't know how to get back to the original data to perform the second search. Thanks!

Comment: @Glenn Note that this is a "simple" solution. If you provide a first name that is not present, it returns nothing, whereas if the first name in question appears more than once (regardless of with the same last name or not), you'll get the whole `characters` array as many times as input names did match. This may or may not be desirable. To always have just one result, define which one you want to receive.

Comment: @Glenn, Re "*by the time I got it, only Ron was left in my list*", Sounds like you were using `... | ... | ... as $last` instead of `( ... | ... | ... ) as $last`

Comment: I was definitely missing the ( ) in my script. But there was also the reuse of .characters to get back to the original data set. As I said in the post, it was a problem with my understanding of how jq handles the data. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have an array of objects called "characters" each containing a "first" and "last" variable.
Now to get the first one. Go characters[0].first which would return. "Fred"
Or characters.[3].last would return "Weasley"
Note the first entry in array is fetched by index 0.
Make sense?

Comment: Correction. "First" needs to be capital and so does "Last". This is not good naming practice tho and I would change to lower case. Something like "firstName" is when you use a capital. Unless objects. Lots of people just use a capital at beginning.

Comment: Well a) that looks like we're just iterating through the array where I'm really looking for a search function. And b) they don't all have a last name.